# Utilizar data table com recurso on demand dentro de um dialog no primefaces

Tags: primefaces

Estou com dificuldade ao utilizar uma `datatable` do `primefaces` com aquele recurso `on demand`. Tento utilizar ela dentro de um `dialog` mas ao abrir com os dados, mas eles não são atualizados e o `scroll` do mouse move a página de anterior pois estou usando `modal = "true"`.

Alguém já conseguiu fazer tal coisa?

Código do `dialog`

```
<p:dialog header="#{lbl['LABEL.TABELATAXA.HISTRICODATABELA.HEADER']}"
    widgetVar="dlgLog" resizable="false" modal="true" height="500"
    width="1000" dynamic="true">
    <ui:include src="#{tabelaTaxasComissoesEmprestimoBean.viewLog}" />
</p:dialog>
```

Código do Viewlog

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head/>

    <h:body>
        <p:dataTable var="log" value="#{tabelaTaxasComissoesEmprestimoBean.logs}"
            emptyMessage="#{lbl['LABEL.TABELATAXA.NAOHAREGISTROLOG.MSG']}"
            styleClass="dataTableNoWrap" scrollRows="15" scrollable="true"
            liveScroll="true" scrollHeight="400" scrollWidth="2500">

            <p:column headerText="#{lbl['LABEL.TABELATAXA.DATAHORA']}"
                styleClass="columnCenter">
                <h:outputText value="#{log.dataHora}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm" />
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="#{lbl['LABEL.TABELATAXA.USUARIO']}">
                <h:outputText value="#{log.usuario.login}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="#{lbl['LABEL.TABELATAXA.OPERACAO']}">
                <h:outputText value="#{log.operacao}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="#{lbl['LABEL.TABELATAXA.DESATIVADO']}"
                styleClass="columnCenter">
                <h:outputText value="#{log.desativada}" converter="boolConverter" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="#{lbl['LABEL.TABELATAXA.NOME']}">
                <h:outputText value="#{log.nome}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="#{lbl['LABEL.TABELATAXA.DESATIVADA']}"
                styleClass="columnCenter">
                <h:outputText value="#{log.desativada}" converter="boolConverter" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column
                headerText="#{lbl['LABEL.TABELATAXA.TABELANAOPODESERVINCULADAASLOJAS']}"
                styleClass="columnCenter">
                <h:outputText value="#{log.tabelaNaoPodeSerVinculadaLojas}" converter="boolConverter" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column
                headerText="#{lbl['LABEL.TABELATAXA.TABELAEXCLUSIVACPGARANTIA']}"
                styleClass="columnCenter">
                <h:outputText value="#{log.tabelaExclusivaParaCPGarantia}" converter="boolConverter" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column
                headerText="#{lbl['LABEL.TABELATAXA.TABELAUTILIZADAFINANCIAMENTOVEICULOS']}"
                styleClass="columnCenter">
                <h:outputText value="#{log.tabelaUtilizadaParaFinanciamentoVeiculos}" converter="boolConverter" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column
                headerText="#{lbl['LABEL.TABELATAXA.ANOFABRICACAODOVEICULO']}">
                <h:outputText value="#{log.anoFabricacaoVeiculoMin} - #{log.anoFabricacaoVeiculoMax}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column
                headerText="#{lbl['LABEL.TABELATAXA.FINANCIAMENTOPERMITIDOOVALORDOVEICULO']}"
                styleClass="columnRight">
                <h:outputText value="#{log.financiamentoPermitidoSobreValorVeiculo}">
                    <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2"
                        maxFractionDigits="2" type="percent" />
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>

            <p:column
                headerText="#{lbl['LABEL.TABELATAXA.ENDIVIDAMENTOPERMITIDOARENDA']}"
                styleClass="columnRight">
                <h:outputText value="#{log.endividamentoPermitidoSobreRenda}">
                    <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2"
                        maxFractionDigits="2" type="percent" />
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Estou usando o `primefaces 4.0`.

Comment: Poste o código do `datatable`do `dialog` para facilitar. Usou o `update="idDoDataTable"` no elemento que abre o `dialog`?

Comment: Desculpe a demora em postar o código mas eu estava em outra demanda e agora voltei para este, mas é o seguinte, gostaria de saber qual a relação entre o tamanho do `dialog` e as propriedades da `datatable` para utilizar este tipo de tabela `on demand`.

Answer (score 1):

Eu consegui fazer o live scroll funcionar colocando um `appendTo="@(body)"` ao `p:dialog` e aumentando a quantidade de linhas da tabela para 50: `scrollRows="50"`. Ou seja, uma quantidade que exija o scroll.

Com uma quantidade pequena de linhas a barra de rolagem vertical não era exibida e, dessa forma, não era possível rolar até o fim da tabela para que ela carregasse mais registros.

Comment: O que esse `appendTo` faz?

Comment: @Macario1983 O `appendTo="@(body)"` faz com que os elementos HTML gerados pelo componente `p:dialog` sejam adicionados no `body` da página, ao invés de ficarem misturados com o componente onde o diálogo está declarado. Isso algumas vezes é desejável porque o componente que contém o `dialog` pode estar oculto ou ter um posicionamento que influencie negativamente no comportamento do modal. Por outro lado, colocar o diálogo no `body` também faz com que os componentes de dentro do diálogo estejam fora do `form` atual. Isso pode ajudar ou atrapalhar, sendo que às vezes é necessário criar outro form